# jquery not working with xml

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I'm having problems using xml with jquery.

This is the xml produced on the page: (firebug copy pasted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<product cookie="The red">
  <timediff>01:09:46</timediff>
  <username>denis</username>
  <price>25</price>
</product>

<product cookie="The red">
  <timediff>01:09:46</timediff>
  <username>denis</username>
  <price>35</price>
</product>
```

On body load, proper function is called.

The jquery code is here:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: parseXml
             });

    });


}

function parseXml(xml)
{
      $("#timer2").html("Hey there");
      $(xml).find("product").each(function()
      {
           $("#timer2").html("Hey there");
      });
}
```

Nothing in parseXml function is working. I think it gets called but it can't find #timer2 (perhaps it's because xml is outputed through a php file?). I have the div id="timer" in body.

Edit: not sure if it's important, but the url "ajax" is a route (using a framework) that leads to this file:

ajaxSuccess.php

```
<?php
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
    //time, username, price, id (so jquery can know what to change)

    foreach($acs as $auction) {

        echo "\n<product", " cookie=\"The red\">\n";
        echo "  <timediff>", $auction['time'], "</timediff>\n";
        echo "  <username>", $auction['username'], "</username>\n";
        echo "  <price>", $auction['price'], "</price>\n";
        echo "</product>\n";


    }
?>
```

Comment: I assume your URL isn't _actually_ being set to "ajax" and that's just mock info for your post?

Comment: I forgot to mention i'm using a framework, so thats a route leading to a php file ajaxSucces.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the relevant bits of the page mark-up for anyone to troubleshoot this fully. You also need a valid XML file: there's no root element in there, you just go straight into your two `product` nodes.

If `parseXml` can't find the element with the id `timer2` then obviously it's dead in the water—the php file which supplies your XML shouldn't affect this in any way that I can see.

I'm a little confused by your last statement. You say you have a div in your page with the id `timer`, but I don't see how that's relevant: it's `timer2` that you're trying to manipulate in this snippet. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, timer2. I'll fix the XML now and get back, thanks for replying :).

Comment: Yep, XML fixed it. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is malformed and can't be parsed: a XML document must have only one document Element. Nest your product elements into another element:

```
<products>
<product cookie="The red">
  <timediff>01:09:46</timediff>
  <username>denis</username>
  <price>25</price>
</product>

<product cookie="The red">
  <timediff>01:09:46</timediff>
  <username>denis</username>
  <price>35</price>
</product>
</products>
```